# How to apply different filter effect to video using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am developing filter effects for video like [this website](https://www.veed.io/tools/video-filters). I am using JavaScript/jQuery, and fabric, but it's not correctly applying the effect to the video.

This is the code I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  canvas.setWidth(480);
  canvas.setHeight(360);

  var video1El = document.getElementById('video1');
  var video1 = new fabric.Image(video1El, {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  });

  canvas.add(video1);
  video1El.load();

  $(document.body).on('click', '#play', function() {
    video1El.play();
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
      color: 'red',
      mode: 'tint',
      alpha: 0.5
    });
    video1.filters = [filter];
  });

  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
    var image = canvas.item(0);
    var backend = fabric.filterBackend;
    if (backend && backend.evictCachesForKey) {
      backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey);
      backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey + '_filtered');
    }
    canvas.item(0).applyFilters();
    canvas.renderAll();
    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="play">play</button>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<video crossorigin="anonymous" id="video1" style="display: none" class="canvas-img" width="480" height="360">
  <source id="video_src1" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

My expectation is to create a video filter. For example, grayscale filter, blur, color filter, RGB filter, shadow, and black and white video. Just like the website link which I added.

i also try below,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "gblur=sigma=5:steps=8" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

but how is this command works , can someone give one example of filter with above command. any other technique is https://www.veed.io/tools/video-filters this site uses ffmpeg.

Comment: ffmpeg also not getting expected output, anyone knows how to make filter effect for video & when download filter effect should keep.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is basically fine. The interesting part is

```js
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
   color:'red',
   mode: 'tint',
   alpha: 0.5
});
```

There you are using the filter `BlendColor`, which is one of many other filters. For instance,

- BaseFilter
- Brightness
- Convolute
- GradientTransparency
- Grayscale
- Invert
- Mask
- Noise
- Pixelate
- RemoveWhite
- Sepia
- Sepia2
- Tint

See the [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/).

However, after `fabric.Image.filters` you may add a filter. For instance, if you want to add the blur effect, you may use `fabric.Image.filters.Blur()`. The first parameter of `Blur()` is an object. In the documentation, you may find, what properties you can pass.

**Example:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
   canvas.setWidth(480);
   canvas.setHeight(360);

   var video1El = document.getElementById('video1');
   var video1 = new fabric.Image(video1El, {
     left: 0,
     top: 0
   });

   canvas.add(video1);
   video1El.load();


   $(document.body).on('click', '#play', function() {
     video1El.play();
     var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Blur({
       blur: 0.5
     });
     video1.filters = [filter];
   });

   fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
     var image = canvas.item(0);
     var backend = fabric.filterBackend;
     if (backend && backend.evictCachesForKey) {
       backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey);
       backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey + '_filtered');
     }
     canvas.item(0).applyFilters();
     canvas.renderAll();
     fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="play">play</button>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<video crossorigin="anonymous" id="video1" style="display: none" class="canvas-img" width="480" height="360">
  <source id="video_src1" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

---

The code above is client-side only. So, if you want the user to download the video, you may need to modify the video by the server and then send it to the client.

Here is an example how you could blur a video, using FFmpeg with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "gblur=sigma=5:steps=8" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4`

This command applies a blur filter with a sigma value of 5 and 8 steps to the video file "input.mp4" and saves the output to "output.mp4" (see the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)).

Follow these steps:

1. Open a command prompt or terminal window on your server.
2. Use `cd <DIRECTORY>` to navigate to the directory where the input video file is located.
3. Enter a FFmpeg command (for instance, the one that you see above) and press enter

Once the command has finished running, the output video file will be saved in the same directory as the input file.

Ensure that you have FFmpeg installed on your server, otherwise you may use a library (see the comments).

Once the video is processed, you may send it to the client.

Comment: this is suppose applies blur effect , but it showing on run time , how to download this blur video or upload to server

Comment: With the library that you use, you are not able to do this. fabric.js creates a canvas to "manipulate" the video. The original video is still available in the source. So the user is able to download the video but without any effects.

Comment: any other library available to download this video with effect.

Comment: Yes, but only possible with a server-side library. And that depends on what backend you use. For instance, if you use PHP, you may try the library PHP-FFMpeg. See https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: is this ffmpeg library available with javascript

Comment: As I said, it should be a server-side library. As long as you are not using NodeJS, JS stays client-side. So using a client-side library, the original video (without any effects) will be loaded in DOM and that is what you don't want. That's why you should use a server-side library.

Comment: can you give example of php ffmpeg with one video filter effect.

Comment: You may find a basic usage on their GitHub page (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#basic-usage) and there is also a good documentation. All filters you may find on https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/tree/master/src/FFMpeg/Filters/Video.

Comment: how this https://www.veed.io/tools/video-filters  site working , is they are using some library.  this ffmpeg so confuse

Comment: For editing the video on the frontend, they are using canvas, just the same as fabric.js. If the user wants to export the video, a request will be sent to their backend. So once the job is done, the backend sends a JSON to the frontend that includes `rendered_urls`, `thumbnail_url` and so on. You check this on the network of your browser. However, you will not see how their backend works.

Comment: this answer not give expected output. anyone knows some tools to be use for video filter effects

Comment: What do you mean by "not give expected output"? Did you try it? I tried to explain how to do it in frontend but also in backend, based on what I see in your comments but not in your question. If there is something else that you want, please edit your question.

Comment: can you show ffmepg one exmple with filter to video, what are https://www.veed.io/tools/video-filters they using, is they are also using ffmpeg.

Comment: I already posted an example with a blur effect. Also, there is a documentation how you could use other effects. As mentioned in my previous comment, you will not be able to see how the backend of veed.io/tools/video-filters works. So they could be using FFmpeg or even not.

Comment: I have updated my answer, so you know how to use the FFmpeg command.

Comment: this is done using command prompt, i want in js or php , so that i can use for web application

Comment: You should read my answer and comments. As I have mentioned, you may also use FFmpeg with a PHP library. See https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg ... there you find an example of how it works.

Comment: can you give one complete example from this library , actually this library confusing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the fabric.js library to apply filters to a video element. However, fabric.js is a library for working with canvas elements, not video elements. Canvas elements are image-based, whereas video elements are video-based, and they have different capabilities and limitations.

You cannot directly apply filters to the video element, but one way to achieve a similar effect is to use a canvas element to draw the video, apply the filters to the canvas, and then display the canvas on top of the video.

You can use the HTML5 canvas API to draw the video on the canvas and set its attributes. You can also use libraries like CamanJS and PixiJS, which both provide an easy way to apply various filters to canvas elements.

Here is an example of how to use CamanJS to apply grayscale filter to a video:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<video id="video" src="your_video.mp4"></video>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        video = document.getElementById('video'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    video.addEventListener('play', function(){
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        Caman("#canvas", function () {
            this.grayscale();
            this.render();
        });
    }, false);
</script>
```

You can apply different filter by replacing the filter name in this example.

Hope this helps and gives you a starting point.

Comment: this sample code not working , not applying grayscale effect to video